# Completely disabling widgets

Tags: widgets, wp-admin

How do I completely remove widget support from a theme/plugin ?

Like removing the *appearance -> widgets page*, and prevent WP from loading widget classes and all widget-related stuff.

Comment: maybe removing the sidebars http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_sidebar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to simply flush the widget code out of the sidebar.php file, as well as the header/footer/post pages if they are using widgets.

However, take a peek at this code snippet (courtesy of [this site](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/06/disable-widget-areas-without-touching-theme-templates)), which you can add to your functions.php file and will disable the widgets. I think this would be a cleaner approach if you're looking to change themes and sill have widgets disabled.

```
<?php 
   add_filter( ‘sidebars_widgets’, ‘disable_all_widgets’ ); 
   function disable_all_widgets( $sidebars_widgets ) 
   { 
      if ( is_home() ) $sidebars_widgets = array( false ); 
      return $sidebars_widgets; 
   } 
?>
```

Note that this will only disable the widgets on your home page, so you'll need to find the additional conditionals for individual pages/posts/etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you make use of the internal functions from `widgets.php`, then it's as easy as this:

```
    // final function makes most sense
    // (useing stuff like `$GLOBALS['wp_widget_factory']` will do nothing better than this ex.)
   // place inside your functions.php  

    unregister_widget( 'some widget' );

    // if my search results are right, these should be the available default widgets 
    // from /wp-includes/widgets.php
    Line 389:   'wp_widget_pages',
    Line 390:   'wp_widget_pages_control',
    Line 391:   'wp_widget_calendar',
    Line 392:   'wp_widget_calendar_control',
    Line 393:   'wp_widget_archives',
    Line 394:   'wp_widget_archives_control',
    Line 395:   'wp_widget_links',
    Line 396:   'wp_widget_meta',
    Line 397:   'wp_widget_meta_control',
    Line 398:   'wp_widget_search',
    Line 399:   'wp_widget_recent_entries',
    Line 400:   'wp_widget_recent_entries_control',
    Line 401:   'wp_widget_tag_cloud',
    Line 402:   'wp_widget_tag_cloud_control',
    Line 403:   'wp_widget_categories',
    Line 404:   'wp_widget_categories_control',
    Line 405:   'wp_widget_text',
    Line 406:   'wp_widget_text_control',
    Line 407:   'wp_widget_rss',
    Line 408:   'wp_widget_rss_control',
    Line 409:   'wp_widget_recent_comments',
    Line 410:   'wp_widget_recent_comments_control'
```

Answer (score 2):

[remove_theme_support('widgets')](http://wpseek.com/remove_theme_support/) won't work because of:

```
function remove_theme_support( $feature ) {
// Blacklist: for internal registrations not used directly by themes.
if ( in_array( $feature, array( 'editor-style', 'widgets', 'menus' ) ) )
    return false;

return _remove_theme_support( $feature );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Widgets" menu item [is added by `wp_widgets_add_menu()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L3133), called in the `_admin_menu` hook, [as set up by `wp_maybe_load_widgets()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L3117). You can disable this by unhooking it from `_admin_menu` or returning false for `load_default_widgets`.

You can also unregister all sidebars as Bainternet suggested, and `remove_theme_support( 'widgets' )`.

Comment: does `remove_theme_support( 'widgets' )` have any effect? I tried it and widgets still show up if you have sidebars defined

Comment: @One Trick Pony: I think it is relatively new, but it is certainly [used in the Admin Bar when adding links to the widget page](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L239).